# Starting IBM InstallationManager fails with the following error

Tags: java, eclipse

while starting eclipse launcher via GUI:

Before that I am doing following steps:

list xauth list, and add xauth

But this produces error below:

```
[user@localhost eclipse]$ ./launcher
00:00.54 ERROR [main] org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory safeLogged
  Application error
  org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
  org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    ...
Launcher:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/configuration/1433246473267.log.
```

Comment: Might be this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94497/56152

Answer (score 0):

I had problem in launching the installation manager for IBM WAS, then I realized that my xming was not started before I launch the ./IBMIM. We can use either xming or cygwin. Please note, I logged into linux terminal from my windows desktop.